# Well defined probability

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given the following probabilistic model

[image: Graphical representation of the probabilistic model]

where $u$ are users of a search engine, $c$ are categories where the queries that $u$ search ($q$) and webs sites that they visit ($w$) are classified.

My question is if the following has necessarily has to hold for $p(c\mid q)$ to be a probability:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^m p(c_i\mid q_j) = 1.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am boiling your question down to:

If $p(c\mid q)$ is a probability, then the following condition must be true:
 $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^m p(c_i\mid q_j) = 1.$$

As stated, that's not correct.  For a fixed value of $q$, $p(c\mid q)$ is a probability on $c$.  An informal definition of this is "The probability of $c$ occurring given that $q$ has already occurred."  So, the following is true:
 $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n p(c_i\mid q_j) = 1.$$